# Feedback MOSFET circuit anaylsis

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, small-signal

I am having difficulty calculating the gain and input resistance of the circuit below.

Neglecting ro, capacitance, and considering Ibias as ideal (infinite resistance), would this mean that the current from M1 is 0 (gm1Vgs)?

And further, indicating that the output voltage is 0?

Regarding the input resistance, I am not sure how to treat small-signal vo. I found a similar case regarding a common source with source degeneration, where the author (Razavi) was calculating the output impedance, and he shorted the small-signal input. I am not sure if this applies to the circuit below. Also, similar to the case above, since gm1Vx = 0, would this mean the input resistance in 0?

M1 is causing me lots of problems. If the input resistance is 0 this would imply that the noise figure would be 0. If you consider a source with resistance Rs, the alpha value (Rin/(Rin+Rs)) is 0, thus the noise from Rs is zero. Meaning the total noise figure would be each noise contribution divided by 0.

[image]
[image]

Comment: it seems that in both your circuits you are missing the incremental source resistance 1/gm

Comment: Neglecting M1 ro, capacitances and Ibias output resistance you paint yourself in the corner of a nonsense circuit, a current source can't be left open.

Comment: I think your \$V_o\$ = 0 is incorrect. Sure no current flows but without the feedback path through M2, the AC gain would be infinite as there is no impedance at the output. Do you understand what this circuit actually does? If there's a small increase at /$V_i/$ what happens at \$V_o\$?

Comment: @carloc *a current source can't be left open* Normally I would agree but this is small signal (so linearized) and there's feedback, which would "limit" what happens on the output. I think if we'd use the formula for circuits with negative feedback that might lead to a solution.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie mmm a kinda of ideal operational amplifier then ...  vi=0 virtually, R1 can be neglected, yes it could make sense, all in all a transresistance amplifier with Rm=-1/gm2. Well a little tricky at least.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie This was an assignment question. We were supposed to calculate the gain and input resistance, then determine the noise figure. A similar circuit is found in rf microelectronics by Razavi (chp 5, Q4). I attempted to use the T-model for transistor M2, which seemed like a more reasonable attempt, but have somehow obtained two different expressions for the gain.

Comment: @carloc I don't really have a choice.

Comment: Oh yes @Bimpelrekkie clarified to me the idea behind your exercise. I find it a little pushing too much but that's the way it's been thought and it's probably okay when seen in context. I believe my previous comment can hint you. BTW there's no need for small signal hypothesis, it's a square root extractor then.

Comment: @carloc Its been awhile since I have looked at an op-amp. Could this be symbolized as vi at the positive terminal with a resistor R1 to ground, then the negative terminal has a resistor feedback of 1/gm2 connected to the output?

Comment: I doubt anyone has solved this attempted design because it is inherently unstable due to high sensitivity of source impedance on gain, R-value of M1 gain bias of M2, and load impedance effects on M1 saturation.  It must be AC coupled and has high gain but spends most of the time in the Triode region.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer yet, a few hints though

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhbeKL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you consider just your M1 MOS and its bias source small signal model you may consider \$g_\mathrm{m}v_\mathrm{i}\$ current dependant generator.

It's open circuit, so the only consistent operation point can be "zero output current" i.e.

$$i_\mathrm{o}=g_\mathrm{m}v_\mathrm{i}=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad v_\mathrm{i}=0$$

So, looking at the input port we have \$(v_\mathrm{i}=0\,;\,i_\mathrm{i}=0)\$

---

In these conditions output voltage could be written as output current over output conductance (zero since it's open circuit)

$$v_\mathrm{o}=-\frac{i_\mathrm{o}}{g_\mathrm{o}}=\frac{0}{0}\;\rightarrow\;\mathrm{undefined}$$

Undefined just means that \$v_\mathrm{o}\$ could be any value.

---

Toghether they form one circuit which exhibits zero input voltage and current (sometimes called virtual ground in english speaking countries) and whatever output voltage.

This is similar to an ideal opamp, the only difference is that our circuit output current has to be zero.
All the above is similar to a [nullor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullor)

So now @user367640, any idea??